# get the iso3 country code

Tags: android

How to get the iso3 country code.when i store the server but it is not store 100% of the database? I am using these code.Please help me Thanks and Advance...

```
     geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
     locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    bestProvider =locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,false);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if(location!=null)
    {
      lat=location.getLatitude();
      lng=location.getLongitude();
    }
    else
     {
    location = new Location("");
    location.setLatitude((double)38.0000000000);
    location.setLongitude((double)-97.0000000000);
    lat =location.getLatitude();
    lng=location.getLongitude();
     }
    Log.e("","Latitude and Longitude"+"Latitude="+lat+"Longitude="+lng);
    try
    {   
    addresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(lat,lng, 1);
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {   
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
    {
     Address address = addresses.get(0);
     Log.e("Address=",""+address);
     locale = address.getCountryCode();
     Log.e("Locale",""+locale);
     Toast.makeText(SongsList.this,  "LocaleName"+locale,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [get the iso country code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529285/get-the-iso-country-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`address.getLocale().getISO3Country();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getISO3Country%28%29)

Comment: This is a wrong answer, you will got a code based on your Locale, not based on geo. For example if you live in US and got to Thailand - you will get Thai geo data but still USA code from Locale.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good working solution.

```
String countryCodeISO2 = address.getCountryCode();
String CountryCodeISO3 = new Locale("", countryCodeISO2).getISO3Country();
```