# get the iso country code

Tags: android

How to get the iso3 country code.when i store the server but it is not store 100% of the database? I am using these code.Please help me Thanks and Advance...

```
 geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
 locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
bestProvider =locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,false);
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
if(location!=null)
{
  lat=location.getLatitude();
  lng=location.getLongitude();
}
else
 {
location = new Location("");
location.setLatitude((double)38.0000000000);
location.setLongitude((double)-97.0000000000);
lat =location.getLatitude();
lng=location.getLongitude();
 }
Log.e("","Latitude and Longitude"+"Latitude="+lat+"Longitude="+lng);
try
{   
addresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(lat,lng, 1);
}
catch (IOException e) 
{   
  e.printStackTrace();
}
if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
{
 Address address = addresses.get(0);
 Log.e("Address=",""+address);
 locale = address.getCountryCode();
 Log.e("Locale",""+locale);
 Toast.makeText(SongsList.this,  "LocaleName"+locale,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the TelephonyManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkCountryIso%28%29

This will get you the country of the network you're attached to.

Answer (score 1):

countryISO3 = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getISO3Country() ?

Comment: I am already using this code.Actually,I have two mobile Samsung galaxy ace and Htc Desire.HTC Desire working Properly(IND)and Samsung Galaxy ace get the country code  United Kingdom(GRB).

Comment: Is there any answer from you?

Comment: `locale = address.getCountryCode();
    Locale loc = new Locale(locale);
    Toast.makeText(SongsList.this, "iso3:"+loc.getISO3Country(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());`

Comment: It does not show any value. When i use the  Locale loc = new Locale(locale);

Answer (score 0):

To get the ISO code from the country:

```
TelephonyManager tm;
tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String loc = tm.getSimCountryIso();
Toast.makeText(SongsList.this, "LocaleName" + loc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I should point out that this gives you the country of the SIM card, which may be different from the country the user actually is, in case of roaming. Also there may be no SIM in the device.